# Aligning a Gridview with another view

Tags: android, gridview

I have an `ImageView`. Below it, I want to have a `GridView` containing lots of smaller images. I want it to look neat... 4 per line, with even spacing top and bottom.

Currently, the spacing is not too bad (even though to my eye the left-to-right-spacing looks a little thinner than the top-to-bottom-spacing) but the thing that I'm really struggling with is the extra margin on the far right.

I want the right edge of the images in the grid view to align perfectly with the right edge of the big image. What am I doing wrong?

Here is an image of what I currently have:

[image]

Here is my layout:

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">



            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/items_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                style="@style/ItemsImage" />

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/items_all_images"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:numColumns="4"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"


                android:verticalSpacing="20dp"


                style="@style/ItemsImage"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

The ItemsImage style is this:

```
<style name="ItemsImage">
    <item name="android:gravity">top|left</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">top|left</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">25dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: i feel gravity should be center to have symmetrical spaces.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I do that then I just have equal size excess space on both the far left edge and far right edge. I want the edges to line up evenly with the `ImageView` above.

Comment: I get it, You need not give the right padding and in XML, set grid width to match parent.

Comment: Could you explain further please, I do not understand?

Comment: The white space you see on the right side of your screen is actually the 25dp padding that you gave in your style. And setting width to match parent will occupy the whole screen.

Comment: May be you need to only use *padding* not *paddingRight* in your *ItemsImage style* and also give *width matchparent of your ImageView*.

Comment: Even if I remove the `ItemsImage` style (which removes the padding) and set the gridview gravity to center - I still have excess white space on the far left and right of the gridview.

Comment: @b85411 did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this is the best way to do this but it can solve the problem.
Add these lines to your activity's onCreate method :

```
YOUR_GRIDVIEW.post(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run(){
    YOUR_GRIDVIEW.setWidth(YOUR_IMAGE.getWidth());
    }
});
```

Comment: `GridView` has no `setWidth()` function? I just see setColumnWidth

Comment: @b85411 Then use setMinimumWidth method

Comment: To be honest I don't think there's a problem with the width of the GridView. If I give it a black background, I can see it aligns... but it seems like there's some internal padding on the individual items.

Answer (score 0):

Define fix width and height for grids and also for image in gridView. In code after grid instance initialized, you can set spacing as follow.

```
GridView gridView;
int gridWidth = 1280;
int gridHeight = 500;
int gridItemWidth = 60;
int gridItemHeight = 50;
int gridRows = 3, gridColumns = 4;
int vSpacing = (gridHeight - (gridItemHeight * gridRows))/gridRows;
int hSpacing = (gridWidth - (gridItemWidth * gridColumns))/gridColumns;
gridView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(gridWidth, gridHeight));  

gridView.setColumnWidth(gridItemWidth);
gridView.setNumColumns(gridColumns);

gridView.setHorizontalSpacing(hSpacing);
gridView.setVerticalSpacing(vSpacing);
```

Set grid width equal to the size of large image above GridView.
Hope it helps you.